# spark sql permission denied user=anonymous

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The error that returns for Spark SQL when the denied user is anonoymous:

```
src:hdfs://ournamenode:8020/tmp/hive/spark-root_hive_2017-02-24_00-40-48_944_8869995689545229744-1/-ext-10000/load_date=20170223/part-07262, dest: hdfs://ournamenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse/p13n.db/message_viewed_new/load_date=20170223/part-07262, Status:true
chmod: changing permissions of 'hdfs://ournamenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse/p13n.db/message_viewed_new/load_date=20170223/part-07262': Permission denied. user=anonymous is not the owner of inode=part-07262
```

Is there anywhere to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using beeline to run queries. One fix is to specify username using the `-n` option.

The problem that causes this permission denied issue is that the "spark-warehouse" directory is created under the "anonymous" user, while files in this directory are created under the user who is running the beeline command.